# Not to allow disable geolocation android

Tags: geolocation

I'm using a cordova with angularJS mobile application for Android.

That is an internal application that uses geolocation and I need to disable the option of letting users disable *only* geolocation in the android device.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Presuming the company you work for provides the devices you can make use of a MDM[1] to manage the configuration of the devices. I don't have any experience setting them up / using them however. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's a nonsense. Device user must have a way to control his/her device anyway.

Moreover, as per recent Google I/O,

> The M Developer Preview introduces a new app permissions model which streamlines the process for users to install and upgrade apps. If an app running on the M Preview supports the new permissions model, the user does not have to grant any permissions when they install or upgrade the app. Instead, the app requests permissions as it needs them, and the system shows a dialog to the user asking for the permission. (from [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html)).

So your app should be ready to keep working even the permission will not be given. At least tell the user what's wrong.

But to avoid such situations it may be a good idea for your app to tell the user about this feature before calling [`requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)).